# Excel loads old version of web addin after source moved to new folder

Tags: visual-studio, excel-addins

I've moved the VS source code for my Excel web addin to a different directory on a new computer.  I made a couple of cosmetic changes, generated a new GUID for the manifest, ran clean and build, and sure enough it builds a new dll. When I click Start, Excel should open automatically and load the new dll into the task pane, but instead it loads the old dll, my heading changes are not there.
I've tried looking for references to old locations, but can't find where it is loading from.
I found a few dll's of the same name, and changed their names or their parent folder names to stop them being picked up, but made no difference.

Comment: I just created a new add-in using the MS tutorial. Same problem, whatever shows the first time can't be changed. I've tried changing Properties of the Web app package to load all files, restarted the computer, no change.